# Preventing Illegal Upload

Tags: web

Imagine a website that allows users to upload files and images so that they can be shared. I wish to prevent users from uploading/sharing illegal content such as copyright materials and child pornography. My website will be hosted on a cloud service, such as google cloud.

1. Does cloud services offer content filtering for my website?
2. Is there any API or similar that I can implement in my coding to
   scan for such uploads?
3. How does sites such  as Dropbox, Google and Facebook presumably avoid illegal
   content?

My question might be a bit vague or perhaps in the wrong forum but I am hoping you can help me and perhaps many others in the right direction so that we can avoid nasty people sharing nasty stuff through our websites. For a good cause.

Comment: Only way to be sure is to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have only two options :

- You check that upload content is legal

Which means that you have to watch every single video, picture or text file that is uploaded to your website

- You tell your users they cannot do it

By putting a disclaimer to upload only legal content, most hosts get away with it. They provide a service so you can declare illegal content and this service checks up declarations...

Yeah that sucks...

Answer (score 0):

If that was the case why isn't illegal content literally everywhere? So there is something. For just copyright materials and child pornography obviously because that's all that you could possibly get into trouble for so not like you would want the long answer. There is a way to pick up on large amounts of files being sent received in x amount of time that are greater than (a) but no larger than (b). Which would have a high probability of copyright pirating. Depends on how you build your website, how the encryption works etc & the monitoring of traffic that is set up. You can have certain events alert you. If you dont do it manually there are companies that do sell their bit of coding but its pricey and you won't own that portion of the code.. Just make sure somewhere on the site has a privacy tab that states upon use of this website user agrees that yadayada and if user doesn't agree to stop using website and depending on jurisdictions any data collected must be deleted upon users request so you have to have that too. If you have no idea I dont think it would be a good idea to start up a web page if its going to lead back to you because there are so much more legalities than copyright materials and child pornography and how sites like Google and Facebook prevent problems from arising isn't a secret. They do have sign ups and startups. Especially Google has it to where you can build with them and they can help walk you through legalities etc & shed light onto other things you might not know that you should. Thats the short answer lol. Good luck.